# Insert data 400 rows but query list have 1 element Realm Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, realm

I have a problem when I insert data 400 rows follows my code.

```
fun saveWith(objext: SpicieObject?) {
        var realm: Realm? = null

        try {
            realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()

            realm.executeTransaction {
                val spicie = realm.createObject(Spicie::class.java, objext?.spicieId)
                spicie.spicie = objext?.spicie
                spicie.breedType = objext?.breedType

                realm.insertOrUpdate(spicie)
            }
        }
        finally {
            if (realm != null) { realm.close() }
        }
    }
```

But when i query all data in this database follow my code.

```
fun getList(): RealmResults<Spicie>? {
        try {
            val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
            val objects = realm.where(Spicie::class.java).findAll()
            return objects
        }
        catch (exception: RealmException) {
            exception.printStackTrace()
            println("Exception in database")
        }

        return null
    }
```

This function will return size of array is 1. Which i am uncertain where function is failure when in seat or query. Please guide me because I new for android and kotlin.

Comment: To check whether 400 rows get inserted into a database, use realm studio https://realm.io/products/realm-studio/
The database file can be extracted either from emulator or rooted device.

Comment: `objext?.spicieId` is probably `null` and you are inserting every element with the id `null`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Because SpicieObject is Object but not Class. Becuase memory of device see a value is same memory. Therefore realm insert overlap data. When i try to change Object to Class. This function can do work! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What does the `Spicie` class look like ? I see you are doing `insertOrUpdate`so I imagine you are doing an update 399 times

Try to log the `objext`'s `spicieId` and be sure it's unique across the iteration